# Sort a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string like the following. The string contains words which contain a number from 0 to 9 in them The number is the position they must have in the resulting string.
If the string is empty, the result will be an empty string

Example: "en5 4terremoto NAS1A regi2stró L0a M6arte u3n"

Resultado:

```
 "L0a NAS1A regi2stró u3n 4terremoto en5 M6arte"
```

**how to go through the chain and order it, taking into account the number of each word?**

Until now, I applied the split method to the original chain to separate them.

```
const mensaje = 'en5 4terremoto NAS1A regi2stró L0a M6arte u3n';

const arr = mensaje.split(' ');
console.log(arr);
```

[image: result]

I appreciate your help

Comment: Please, don't post images of text. Type the text

Comment: What's the next step then? Seems like regular `sort` would work, but you'd want a custom sorting method. What would that custom sorting method need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take each word, and remove all non-digits from it (with a regular expression), and use that as index in a result array:

```js
const mensaje = "en5 4terremoto NAS1A regi2stró L0a M6arte u3n";

const result = [];
for (const word of mensaje.split(" ")) {
    result[word.replace(/\D/g, "")] = word;
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Or just take out the digits:- `mensaje.split(' ').map(s => result[s.match(/\d+/)]=s)`

Comment: Using `.map` like that is not advised. Then use `.forEach`

Comment: @Ben, updated with that input. Thanks.

Comment: At the end of the day I prefer reduce:- `mensaje.split(' ').reduce((result, s) => (result[s.match(/\d+/)]=s, result), [])`

Comment: `match` returns an array, so this involves an extra step.

Comment: @trincot
Your answer has worked for me, please could you give me a more detailed explanation about this: ```result[word.replace(/\D/g, "")] = word;```

Comment: `\D` means "not-a-digit". `/\D/g` is a regular expression with the **g**lobal flag set. `.replace(/\D/g, "")` replaces all non-digits with the empty string, meaning that only digit(s) remain. So that could be "2" or "5", ....etc. This is used as an index in the  `result` array, and `= word` sets the content at that index. Eventually all indexes in the range 0..6 will receive a word.

Comment: @trincot
Thanks for your answer, now I find myself applying this to pseudocode, and I don't translate the for into pseudocode, could you guide me with the pseudocode?

Comment: `arr = mensaje.split(" ")` and `for i = 0 to len(arr) - 1` and `result[word[i].getdigit()] = word` ... something like that. pseudo code has no strict rules.